# SELECT Query where date column is X ago where X is another column

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to run a query where a date column is so many days / months ago using `NOW() - INTERVAL` but the number of days / months is in another column called `payment_period`

```
SELECT * 
FROM customer_subscriptions 
WHERE 
    status = 'Active' AND (
        ( auto_renew = '1' AND expiry_date <= '".date("Y-m-d")."') 
        OR (last_charge NOW() - INTERVAL payment_period)
    )
```

Comment: Days or months? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/expressions.html#temporal-intervals

Comment: it'll be defined in the database column `payment_period`

Comment: You wouldn't need to wait a day for an answer, if you had provided an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) from beginning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> last_charge NOW() - INTERVAL payment_period

You are missing two things:

- an operator between the dates to compare (>=)
- a unit for the interval

Assuming that payment_period is expressed as days, you want :

```
last_charge >= NOW() - INTERVAL payment_period DAY
```

Another possibility is to store the `unit` in another column, and then :

```
last_charge >= CASE
    WHEN unit = 'DAY'   THEN NOW() - INTERVAL val DAY
    WHEN unit = 'MONTH' THEN NOW() - INTERVAL val MONTH
    -- ... other supported units ...
END
```

Comment: the unit will be in the database field. for example, it will say `1 DAY` or `2 MONTHS`

Comment: @charlie : no, you cannot define intervals dynamically like this... In this case you would better store the `unit` in a separated column and use `CASE` : see my updated answer.

Comment: i see, that makes sense. could i use the same column for the unit and the value? is it possible to split a column at the space? so `1 DAY` would split into `1` and `DAY`

Comment: @charlie : it would be simpler and better design to use two different columns. But of course you can always manage to split the string, for example with `SUBSTR()` and `INSTR()`.

Comment: @charlie : if my answer was helpful to you and properly responded to your question, please consider upvoting/accepting it. Thanks !